# BDD Framework for Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, maven, bdd, sonarqube

Is there some BDD framework for Java Swing? Something like [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) working with Maven and Sonar could help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potentially you could use [Cucumber-JVM](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) for this which works great with Maven.

For example you could say,

```
When I click this button
Then this should happen
```

This may be possible but it will depend on how you have designed the project and if the swing interface is abstracted from the business layer. Not really sure what you wan't to do with Sonar.

Comment: I want to show the test results within Sonar. It seems possible with Cucumber-JVM.

Comment: I think I will need some framework like [Fest](http://code.google.com/p/fest/) working with Cucumber-JVM to interact with Swing.

Comment: I don't know about sonar but jenkins has a cool plugin for cucumber-jvm https://github.com/masterthought/jenkins-cucumber-jvm-reports-plugin-java

Answer (score 0):

[Ginkgo4j](http://paulcwarren.github.io/ginkgo4j/) is a port of Ruby's RSpec and has the advantage of being 100% expressable in Java.  Therefore can be used to test any Java written on top of any Java framework and integrates fully with maven/surefire/sonar.

```
@RunWith(Ginkgo4jRunner.class)
public class MySwingTests {
  {
    Describe("My Swing Tests", () -> {
      Context("when button X is clicked", () -> {
        It("should do this", () -> {
          // assertions
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```